# assert : weird comparison result Python

Tags: python

Something weird. I want to test if a sum of a tuple elements is 1 and then assert if not.

```
my_tuple=(0.8,0.2,0)
assert((sum(my_tuple)==1))
```

This works. It works for other tuples like ( 1,0,0) or (0.1,0.2,0.7). 
But it raises an error for this tuple (0.7,0.2,0.1) eventhough the sum is clearly 1 !!

Do you have any idea about this ? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide us with an example of how did you make the tests with the other tuples, exactly how you wrote them in the code and etc.

Comment: hmm this is strange. `sum((0.8,0.2,0))==1` is `True` but `sum((0.7,0.2,0.1))==1` is `False`. The latter evaluates to `0.9999999999999999` for some reason.

Comment: Just like I showed in the post. For example to test the tuple (0.7,0.2,0.1)  i do this : my_tuple=(0.1,0.2,0.7)   and then assert((sum(my_tuple)==1))